# Dealing with the dot product of two gradients

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm dealing with the expression below

$$ \nabla(f^*(r)e^{i\theta}) \cdot \nabla(f(r)e^{-i\theta})  $$

where $f$ is a complex function that vanishes at the boundary. I need to show that when this above expression is integrated over a volume, then the integral is equal to zero. Can I do this without having to specify coordinates for the $\nabla$ operator?

Comment: I cant just move the two exponentials out of the differentiation right?